# C# reference structure item in a List to get shorter name in loop and less processing to access indexed item?

Tags: c#

I have something like:

```
public struct sMyStruct
{
  public double Whatever;
  public DateTime When;
  // etc..
}

public class MyClass {
  public List<sMyStruct> m_MyVaraibleNameWForTheList = new List<sMyStruct>();
  // etc..
}

public MyClass m_MyClass=new CMyClass();

public void MyFunction()
{
  for (int i=m_MyClass.m_MyVaraibleNameWForTheList.Count-1;i>=0;i--) {
    // This is where I want to shorten the name - but this doesn't work.
    ref var item = ref m_MyClass.m_MyVaraibleNameWForTheList[i];
  }
}
```

As shown above, I want to reference it with a shorter name and let the compiler optimize it all so I don't have index it every time I want to use it within the loop (and look at long names that clutter it up - in reality the item I want is much deeper within additional classes so the name gets even longer).

I don't want to use `foreach` here because I don't want to `Reverse` the list itself.  I also don't really want to copy the structure over each time.

Is there a way to do this with C# ?

TIA!!

Comment: Is it an option to have a variable with a short name for the list instead like `List<sMyStruct> l = m_MyClass.m_MyVaraibleNameWForTheList;`?